# Piecewise function for points

Tags: pgfplots, conditionals, foreach

How to construct points by condition avoiding the repetition of  `\addplot`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0.3,0.4,...,1} {
            \addplot coordinates { #1 < 1 ? (#1,#1) : (5,5)  }; % if \i < 1 then put (x,y) on axis,  else put (5,5) point on axis
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `samples at`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot[blue,mark=*,samples at={0.3,0.4,...,1}]  
      ({ifthenelse(x < 1,x,5)},{ifthenelse(x < 1,x,5)}); % if \i < 1 then put (x,y) on axis,  else put (5,5) point on axis
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

which can be made a bit more elegant with `declare function`,

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=ifthenelse(\x<1,\x,5);}]
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot[blue,mark=*,samples at={0.3,0.4,...,1}]  
      ({f(x)},{f(x)}); % if \i < 1 then put (x,y) on axis,  else put (5,5) point on axis
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can build up the a list and plot it. Some care has to be taken since when pgf iterates over lists with `...` it introduces small errors, which is why the condition reads `\ifdim\i pt<0.98pt` and not `\ifdim\i pt<1pt`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \edef\mylst{}
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i in {0.3,0.4,...,1}  {%
    \ifdim\i pt<0.98pt
     \edef\mylst{\mylst (\i,\i)}
    \else
     \edef\mylst{\mylst (5,5)}
    \fi
    }%
    \addplot coordinates {\mylst};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```